# Do any sax libraries support exiting early based on some condition?

Tags: java, xml, sax

I have an xml file that looks like:

```
<root>
<application-key>ABC2349293493</application-key>
...
..
</root>
```

The xml file is rather large, and I only need to get the application-key to see if this request should be rate limited.

My server is getting pounded, so I need a way to rate limit requests without having to read the entire xml.

DOM is out of the question because of the memory footprint.

I am happy with SAX, but with xerces you are not able to stop processing of the xml since it is a push model.  The only way I know so far is the throw an exception.

Do any of the other sax libraries support exiting early gracefully?

Answer (score 3):

[StAX (Streaming Api for XML) pull parser.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbem.html) Choosing the proper implementation is also important: [Best StAX Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121251/best-stax-implementation).

P.S. I still think SAX way of doing things (throwing an exception) is simpler.

Comment: A pull parser like StAX makes this very natural to do. It's also, IME, a much more convenient programming model generally.

Comment: do you think throwing an exception is going to make it slower than stax?

Comment: @Blankman it is harder to tell which one is more performant without profiling. But I doesn't think it matters much for this simple case.

Answer (score 2):

An exception is indeed the only option in the spec that is available to exit the parsing process. As outlined [Java. Sax parser. How to manually break parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964315/java-sax-parser-how-to-manually-break-parsing) or [How to stop parsing xml document with SAX at any time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345293/how-to-stop-parsing-xml-document-with-sax-at-any-time).

Switch to a pull parser if you REALLY don't want to use an exception, but I don't think it really matters.

Comment: Does it cause any performance issue though?  that is what I am concerned about.  I'm going to test it but theoretically exceptions are slow correct?

Comment: @Blankman - "theoretically" compared to what?  compared to executing a single machine instruction, maybe.  compared to parsing xml, doubtful.